# How to integrate highchart range slider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using angularjs highchart by integrating the DI of `highcharts-ng`

I have created different type of charts by following options

```
var chart = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: chartData.name
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: chartData.subname
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled:true,
                selected: 1
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: chartData.x.title
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: chartData.y.title
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: chartData.data[0].name,
                data: chartData.data[0].data,
                dashStyle: 'longdash'
            }, {
                 name: chartData.data[1].name,
                data: chartData.data[1].data,
                dashStyle: 'dot'
            }, {
                 name: chartData.data[2].name,
                data: chartData.data[2].data
            }]
        }
```

I have added rangeslider options but its not reflecting in chart.

How to integrate highchart range slider in angualrjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a reference to [highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) instead of highcharts.  Both are compatible with highcharts-ng, but only highstock supports rangeSelector.  Then, move `rangeSelector` into the `options` object.  Note - "range slider" functionality is called [`navigator`](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator) in the highstock docs, and must also be added to `options`.

```
var chart = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

Here is a demo, from highcharts-ng's GitHub page:
http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/r88yszk0/